# how to insert an array into a single db field separated by comma in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["save"]))
    {
        $sql="select * from tb_transport";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $arr[]=$row["id"];  
        }

        echo $arr;

    }

?>
```

here on click of a button i am selecting all id's present in a database and storing them into an array...now i want this array to get stored in a database in a single field separated by comma...can anyone suggest me something that how can  do this ??

Comment: No, you really don't want that. Really really. What for? And what is your issue in doing it?

Comment: I suggest you not to do this. It's almost ever asking for trouble.

Comment: i want to insert a record of all the values saved in db..actually i have the data insrted in a table but i want a collective result in a single field also

Comment: Do you specifically want a comma seperated list, or is that just your first thought. What will you do with this comma seperated list if you have it?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4):

You can implode the array, it will be converted into comma separated string then save it.
[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: What if the array contains a string containing a comma?

Comment: Comma will be added, it depends on context.

Comment: Sure a comma will be added, but then when exploding there's suddenly one element more in the array.

Comment: @wumm It depends on context sir. Here as per my understanding he only needs to convert array into string of comma separated elements.Your point is valid and if it is required then you can add other glue string like pipe sign or something else.